Proving than meeting is quicker than hitting on Markov chain (Book of Aldous and Fill); A martingales' issue
I am trying to fully understand the proof that the meeting time a Markov chain is always less than the hitting time, following the book of Aldous and Fill (Prop. 14.5, page 462). While this is a undeniably a great book, I have trouble filling some gaps in the proof, especially the part of showing that some random process is a martingale. That is why I post this.
For context, we consider two independent Markov chains $(X_n)_n$ and $(Y_n)_n$ over the same finite set of states $I$ and same transitions matrix $P=(p_{ij})_{ij\in I}$. We assume that the chain is irreducible and reversible, and we denote with $\pi$ the stationary distribution. Then we define for $y\in I$ the hitting time $T_y$ and the meeting time $M$ with:
\begin{align*}
T_y &= \min\{n\geq 0 \mid X_n=y\}, \\
M &= \min\{n\geq 0 \mid X_n = Y_n \}.
\end{align*}
The hitting time of the Markov chain is $\tau_{hit}=\max_{i,j\in I}E_iT_j$ and the meeting time is $\tau_{meet}=\max_{i,j\in I}E_{i,j}M$.
We have this theorem which hold for any irreducible and reversible Markov chain:
Theorem: $\tau_{hit}\leq\tau_{meet}$
The proof Aldous and Fill can be split into three steps:
(a) Define the function $f(i,j)$ for $i,j\in I$ by $f(i,j) = E_iT_j - E_\pi T_j $ and then show that:
$$
\text{if $i\neq j$, then } f(i,j) = 1 + \sum_{k\in I}p_{ik}f(k,j) \tag{1},$$ $$
\text{if $i\neq j$, then } f(i,j) = 1 + \sum_{k\in I}p_{jk}f(i,k) \tag{2}.
$$
(b) Define the random variables $V_n = 2n + f(X_n,Y_n)$ and $W_n = V_{\min(n,M)}$. Then show that $W$ is a martingale.
(c) Apply the optional stopping theorem with the stopping time $M$ to finish the proof.
I now have one main question and one secondary question. My main question is: How do I prove that $(W_n)_n$ is indeed a martingale?
The filtration is $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$, where $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_0,Y_0,\ldots,X_n,Y_n$. So we want to show that: $$E[W_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=W_n.$$
This is my attempt:
\begin{align} E[W_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n] &=  E[W_{n+1}1_{M\leq n}\mid\mathcal{F}_n] +  E[W_{n+1}1_{M>n}\mid\mathcal{F}_n] \tag{3}
\end{align}
The left summand is equal to $W_{n}1_{M\leq n}$, so let's focus on the right part. Applying the definition of $W_n$ when $n<M$ and using the linearity of the expectation:
\begin{align}
E[W_{n+1}1_{M>n}\mid\mathcal{F}_n] &=(2n+2)1_{M>n} + \sum_{i',j'\in I}f(i',j')E[1_{X_{n+1}=i'}1_{Y_{n+1}=j'}1_{M>n}\mid\mathcal{F}_n] \\
&=(2n+2)1_{M>n} + \sum_{i',j',i,j\in I}1_{X_n=i}1_{Y_n=j}p_{ii'}p_{jj'}f(i',j')1_{M>n} \tag{4}
\end{align}
Now let us focus on the quantity $\alpha_{ij}:=\sum_{i',j'\in I}p_{ii'}p_{jj'}f(i',j')$, define for any $i,j$. If we achieve to show that: $$ \text{for $i\neq j$, }\alpha_{ij}=f(i,j)-2,\tag{5}$$ we are done. Indeed, as the quantity (4) become $(2n+f(X_n,Y_n))1_{M>n}=W_n1_{M>n}$ and then (3) become $W_n$ as desired.
My trouble is proving (5). Here is the furthest I come, assume that $i\neq j$:
\begin{align}
\alpha_{ij}&=\sum_{i',j'\in I}p_{ii'}p_{jj'}f(i',j')\\
&= \sum_{i',j'\in I, j'\neq i}p_{ii'}p_{jj'}f(i',j') + \sum_{i'\in I}p_{ii'}p_{ji}f(i',i)\\
&= \sum_{j'\in I, j'\neq i}p_{jj'}(f(i,j')-1) + \sum_{i'\in I}p_{ii'}p_{ji}f(i',i) \text{, by applying (1) to the left summand} \\
&= f(i,j)-1-p_{ji}f(i,i) -(1 - p_{ji}) + \sum_{i'\in I}p_{ii'}p_{ji}f(i',i) \text{, because (2) and $P$ is stochastic} \\
&= f(i,j) -2 +\left(-f(i,i)+1+\sum_{i'\in I}p_{ii'}f(i',i)\right)p_{ji}
\end{align}
Which is (5) but with the extra term $\left(-f(i,i)+1+\sum_{i'\in I}p_{ii'}f(i',i)\right)p_{ji}$. A reformulation of my main question is: is it true that $f(i,i)=1+\sum_{i'\in I}p_{ii'}f(i',i)$?
My secondary question is part of (c). After applying the optional stopping theorem, stating that $E_{x,y}W_0=E_{x,y}W_M$, which unfold to $E_xT_y-E_\pi T_y= 2E_{x,y}M-E_\pi T_{Y_M}$. To conclude the proof, I need to show that $E_\pi T_{Y_M}\leq\tau_{hit}$, and for this, I want use the formula $$E_\pi T_j=\sum_{i\in I}\pi(i)E_iT_j, \tag{6}$$ but I have no other justification for this than my intuition. So is the equation (6) true, and if so, based on which principles?
